# Book recommendations for a meaningful book about mathematics

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation

I am looking for a book that shows how meaningful mathematics is in life, how it affects the way we think and how it is applicable in the wide range of disciplines. It can very well touch on different topics like religion, nature or an abuse of mathematical methods (e.g in statistics).

I realize that such books usually do not require a broad knowledge of mathematics but in case they do it would be even better!

Comment: I think you might be interested in *How Not to Be Wrong: The Power of Mathematical Thinking* by Jordan Ellenberg.

Answer (score 1):

Try the book [The Mathematics of Everyday Life](https://www.maa.org/press/maa-reviews/the-mathematics-of-everyday-life). (link to an MAA review)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe *Love and Math*, by Edward Frenkel.